# Can you identify this small, formerly flowering houseplant?

Tags: identification, houseplants, flowering

I received this plant as a gift. It had flowers, but they have long since vanished. The plant seems to be doing fine- it's been putting out new leaves, and it's been six months. I recently moved it into a larger pot, and it's been receiving a few hours of direct sunlight every day. After someone identifies it, I'd be glad to know what to do to get it to flower again, one day.

[image: the unidentified plant]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a [Kalanchoe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalanchoe), and they typically bloom in spring so it's natural for yours not to be bloom now.  (You can find them blooming in the stores all year round, but those plants have been forced into bloom by their growers.)

To get it to bloom again, give it:

- plenty of light -- where you have it looks OK.
- moderate water while it's growing, less during winter months. (It's a succulent, so it can stand being a little dry for a while).
- regular fertilizer; I use a slow-release fertilizer on mine and feed it a couple of times a year.
- room temperatures: they don't like being cold.  I move mine away from its normal home on my kitchen windowsill when it's very cold outside.

It's also a good idea to pinch out the growing tips of the shoots, otherwise the plant can get straggly.

Comment: Use fertilizer that has the N (nitrogen) equal to or lower than the numbers of P (phosphorus) and K (potassium).  5-5-5 or 14-14-14 or 5-7-6 or 10-14-14.  This will produce reproductive growth instead of vegetative growth and you should get flowers.