# What is this succulent plant with clumps of small yellow flowers above large leaves?

Tags: identification, houseplants, succulents

I just got this succulent plant as a gift. It has small four-petal yellow flowers in large clumps above the large leaves.

Can some one please tell me what it is?

[image]

Comment: It's a [_Kalanchoe blossfeldiana_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalanchoe_blossfeldiana), commonly just called Kalanchoe. It likes bright light, regular watering and feeding, and it doesn't like cold. For more details, see this [other question](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4608/can-you-identify-this-small-formerly-flowering-houseplant)

Comment: Yes, this is a kalanchoe as described in the link http://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/4610/499

Comment: The wikipedia entry has pink flowers, the *duplicate* link in the comment above shows something with no flowers and the leaves look different, how sure are you that this is that plant?  ..... keep in mind, I know nothing about plants.  Thanks!

Comment: The Wikipedia article also says that the flowers can be "red, purple, orange, yellow and white"

Comment: It is a Kalanchoe blossfeldiana, as Niall said ![chal](http://images.suite101.com/625190_com_kalanchoe2.jpg)

Comment: Hi Naill and Kevinsky, want share points? I guessed just a kalanchoe, but not the variety - The credit is yours =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a Kalanchoe blossfeldiana, **as Niall and Kevinsky said**.
I found this very nice image, very similar to that in the question

[lal http://images.suite101.com/625190_com_kalanchoe2.jpg](http://images.suite101.com/625190_com_kalanchoe2.jpg)

---

**EDIT
@ FOR Niall**

modern hybrid Kalanchoe
[image: hibrid]

Kalanchoe tomentosa- Panda Kalanchoe
[image: tomentosa]

Kalanchoe beharensis- tree form
[image: behar]

Kalanchoe blossfeldiana cv. Calandiva [image: cal]
<sub>(source: [toptropicals.com](http://toptropicals.com/pics/garden/m1/raznozvet2/Kalanchoe_blossfeldiana7389.jpg))</sub>

Enjoy =)))