# What is this small houseplant with serrated, waxy-looking leaves?

Tags: identification, houseplants

A friend of mine got this office plant as a present and is wondering what it's called and how it needs to be taken care of. Any ideas?

[image: Office plant]

Comment: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4608/can-you-identify-this-small-formerly-flowering-houseplant

Comment: It does look similar

Comment: definitely kalanchoe

Comment: A better photo would help. It looks like a sad Creeping Charlie to me. http://healthyhomegardening.com/Plant.php?pid=504

Comment: That is not creeping Charlie, I have seen far too much of that. This is a succulent, creeping Charlie is a lawn vine from hell!!!

Comment: Hi Mathias. Have you looked at the question Niall C. linked to in his comment? Your plant looks like that one. If you don't think so, would you please [edit] your question to say why? If the other looks good to you, then I hope that thorough answer will help you care for and enjoy your plant!