# What is this potted plant with dark green leaves and clumps of red flowers?

Tags: identification, houseplants, succulents

A co-worker gave me this pretty plant, but she doesn't know what it is. Can someone help identify it?

[image]

It's the one with the red flowers. Thanks!

Comment: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4608/can-you-identify-this-small-formerly-flowering-houseplant

Comment: This question has flowers!

Answer (score 5):

This is a [Kalanchoe blossfeldiana](http://davesgarden.com/guides/articles/view/2673/) or Christmas Kalanchoe. It could be one of many cultivars.

It is characterized by its succulent leaves, brilliantly colored 4 petal flowers.  It requires little but regular watering if you want it to flower again.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Graham, still learning the ropes here.